# Average ten values and then loop through to the next ten values until there are no more values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset that consists of 5 different variables. As shown below.

```
Value1          Value 2     Value 3        Value 4          Value 5
1200.08031  104.9940186  28.05707932    23.90201187      1198.955811
1200.01948  105.0005951  28.05075455    23.88057899      1198.984619
1199.9152   105.0007782  28.04256058    23.86779976      1199.18042
1199.90651  105.0114594  28.05139923    23.90410423      1199.148926
1200.01079  104.9975433  28.05404663    23.89129448      1198.660034
1199.97603  104.9940186  28.0475502     23.91586685      1198.932129
1199.89782  105.0007782  28.04875183    23.87851715      1198.928833
1200.01948  105.0056458  28.04198837    23.91583633      1199.087524
1199.87175  105.0026855  28.04278946    23.91485214      1198.896851
1199.97603  105.0054626  28.04265976    23.9235096       1199.426514
```

Each of these variables has around 15,000 data points. To reduce the number of data points I want to average every ten data points into one data point and assign this value to a cell on another sheet. I want it to look like:

```
Value1Avg       Value 2Avg     Value 3Avg     Value 4Avg     Value 5Avg
1200.08031     104.9940186  28.05707932    23.90201187     1198.955811
```

I cannot get the average function to loop through every ten data points.

I have tried to run a loop that goes through each column and averages the values and places them on a different sheet, but I am not incrementing the variables correctly I believe.

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("RawData")
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("FilteredData")

ii = 2
j = 11
dd = 2
k = 20
n = 1

LastRow = sht1.Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    Set Myrange = sht1.Range("E" & ii, "E" & j)
    sht2.Range("A" & n).Value =Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Myrange)
    Set Myrange = sht1.Range("B" & ii, "B" & j)
    sht2.Range("B" & n).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Myrange)
    Set Myrange = sht1.Range("C" & ii, "C" & j)
    sht2.Range("C" & n).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Myrange)
    Set Myrange = sht1.Range("H" & ii, "H" & j)
    sht2.Range("E" & n).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Myrange)
    Set Myrange = sht1.Range("D" & ii, "D" & j)
    sht2.Range("D" & n).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Myrange)
    ii = ii + 10
    j = j + 10
    n = n + 1
Next i
```

I expect to go to sheet 2 and see the averages, but I get:

> "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

Comment: Instead of `"A & n"` use `"A" & n` - `n` is a variable, so do not include it in quotes.

Comment: Variables should be outside of quotes: `"E" & ii & ":E" & j`. Well you've got tons of instances of this as @braX has pointed out too.

Comment: You say `i = 3`, then go on to say from `i = 1 to LastRow`

Comment: Thank you for your comments you are correct, I have fixed the quote error and the i= 3 error. However, now I am getting the error code "Unable to get the Average property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Comment: @RachelRoberts Can you edit your post with your updated code?

Comment: I have updated the code with edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a potential alternative that may be a little easier to follow by making use of nested loops. This way you do not have to complete the average for each column one by one, instead you can just have your action line written once situated inside a row & column loop.

Simplifying variables will also make this easier to update / debug in the future.

```
Sub Jeeped()

Dim rd As Worksheet: Set rd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData")
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FilteredData")

Dim LR As Long
LR = rd.Range("A" & rd.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim c As Long 'Column Loop
Dim r As Long 'Row Loop
Dim x As Long 'Paste counter
x = 2

Dim TempAverage As Range

For r = 2 To LR Step 10
    For i = 1 To 5                                                      '<-- (Columns A - D)
        Set TempAverage = rd.Range(rd.Cells(r, i), rd.Cells(r + 9, i))
        ws.Cells(x, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(TempAverage)
    Next i
  x = x + 1
Next r

End Sub
```

---

*assumes your variables span Columns A:D on `RawData` and that the values will be pasted on `FilterdData` on `Columns A:D` as well. You can modify the loops to place them in the correct location*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKcpe.png

Comment: This worked great thank you! And was much simpler than how I was originally trying.

Comment: If this will be a running list you may need to modify the `x` variable to be a last row count on your `FilteredData` sheet. If so, just mimic the `LR` calc used above